# Can Dapp respond to an API evocation which in turn calls an EOA and then evoke a contract?

Tags: contract-design, dapps, dapp-design

Can a Dapp (leveraging web3.js) respond to an API evocation from an external system which in turn calls an EOA and then evoke a contract on the blockchain?

1. External system calls a Dapp
2. Dapp calls a smart contract via an EOA

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Dapp, server, bot signs a transaction from EOA. Contract responds. The external world is outside the scope of the smart contract.

EOAs that are recognized and authorized to perform certain functions are inside the scope of the smart contract. For example, a whitelist of trusted bots.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! One question - Does dApp in a permissioned blockchain such as quorum means introducing single point of failure? If the node js dapp fails I wont be able to move forward

Comment: You'd want to make it appropriately reliable.

Comment: Time to bring some infrastructure people into the room and tell them you want to build a fault-tolerant service that will watch something and sign transactions.